# Why doesn't type inference work in this case

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I want to write a comparator which sorts objects having a parameter of type Number. I created a generic dto as follows

```
public class GenericSortingDTO<T extends Number> {

private T parameter;

public T getParameter() {
    return parameter;
}

public void setParameter(T parameter) {
    this.parameter = parameter;
}
}
```

I created a comparator like this

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class WeightComparator implements Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Number>> {

@Override
public int compare(GenericSortingDTO<Number> o1,
        GenericSortingDTO<Number> o2) {

     return new BigDecimal(o1.getParameter().toString()).compareTo(new     BigDecimal(o2.getParameter().toString()));
}
}
```

Now, I try to create an instance of an integer comparator

```
Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Integer>> genericComparator =  new WeightComparator();
```

But I get an error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from WeightComparator to Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Integer>>`

But it doesn't give a compilation error when I do this:

```
Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Number>> genericComparator =  new WeightComparator();
```

Can somebody explain this behaviour?

Comment: `Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Integer>>` is not a `Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Number>>`. There are numerous posts on SO discussing this concept of Java generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler to declare your class like this:

```
public static class GenericSortingDTO<T extends Number>
                             implements Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<T>> {
  //your current code here

  @Override
  public int compare(GenericSortingDTO<T> o1, GenericSortingDTO<T> o2) {
    return new BigDecimal(o1.getParameter().toString()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(o2.getParameter().toString()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
GenericSortingDTO<Integer>
```

and

```
GenericSortingDTO<Number>
```

are two disparate types. There is no hiererachical relationship between them. By implication the same is true of

```
Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Integer>>
```

and

```
Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<Number>>
```

These two types are not assignment-compatible, therefore the compiler error.

However, there is no need to restrict your `WeightComparator` as you have. You are allowed to declare

```
public class WeightComparator implements Comparator<GenericSortingDTO<? extends Number>> {
  @Override public int compare(GenericSortingDTO<? extends Number> o1, GenericSortingDTO<? extends Number> o2) {
    return ...;
  }
}
```

And since `Number`s are comparable on their own, you'll be able to provide a meaningful implementation.